# VMwarePlayer on debian. Missing kernel modules

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, vmware

Today I changed my workstation to Debian. As Ubuntu is not nearly stable. Now I installed VMware player. I started it and got a message "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and and loaded into the running kernel. Kernel headers for version2.6.32-5-amd64 were not found" , below a field were I can give a file location. What should I do now? I never faced such a situation.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install `linux-header-2.6.32.5-amd64`.

Comment: @jw013 That should be `headers` with a "s". I made the same mistake when I first answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to compile kernel modules for your running kernel, you need install the kernel headers. The following command should work:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

Comment: Thank. but waht means $(uname -r)?

Comment: @DevNoob type it in as-is. It inserts the output of the `uname -r` command into the command line arguments.

Comment: @DevNoob you don't have enough rep to vote yet, but you can still mark this as your accepted answer (if you'd like) by clicking the large checkmark under the voting arrows. The [FAQ has pictures](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @DevNoob: `$(uname -r)` will automatically be replaced by the version of the kernel you're running.